# How to bundle kotlinjs dependencies into a single file

Tags: maven, kotlin, kotlin-maven-plugin

Both from reading documentation and experimentation it's relatively easy to configure `kotlin-maven-plugin` in a multimodule maven project so that kotlin code in one module depending on code in some other module successfully resolves this dependency.

However, I don't understand how bundle all dependencies into a single file but rather used all compiled files independently.

So, my question is - speaking of maven, what is the minimal configuration for compiling to javascript target and bundle all project dependencies into a file?

Comment: is this kotlin or javascript?

Comment: it's kotlin compiled to javasciprt

Comment: If switching to Gradle is an option, https://github.com/kotlin/kotlin-frontend-plugin will take care of this for you. JetBrains does not provide an equivalent plugin for Maven.

Comment: @yole what about npm package, kotlinc-js-api? it's easier to embed in our maven build.